# Hover effect on "a" element not working but works for buttons(same page)

Tags: css, hover, anchor

**HTML**

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-image: url(tiger.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;   
  font-family:'Sigmar One', cursive;
}

.logo{
  color:white;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  opacity: .8;
}

.menu{
  list-style: none;   
  list-style-position: inside;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -120px;
  font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
}

ul li{
  display: inline-block;   
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;    
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition-duration: 2s;          
}

**a:hover{
  color: green;
  opacity: .9;
}**
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Layout with HTML and CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Layout1.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Modak&family=Sigmar+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>

    <h1 class="logo">Tiger</h1>

    <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Timings</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Diet</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Weather<a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="content">
        <h1 class="uc">I'm the true king of the jungle</h1>
        <p class="bc" style="text-transform: capitalize important!;">Tiger are mavericks,these big cats are extremely fierce and its heart pumping
            to come accross one in real worlk.
        </p>
        <div class="btn">
            <button class="a">White Tiger</button>
            <button class="a">Yellow Tiger</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***I've tried:
li a:hover
ul li a:hover
.menu ul li a:hover
.menu a:hover***

Hi guys please see the see css file for a:hover styling, I have used hover on other elements and its working fine, I've tried several combination with the block and lists, still not working. Please guide me on this as why its not working.

```
.content
{
    
    align-items: center;
    text-align:center;
    /* border: 1px yellow solid; */
    margin-top: 200px;
    color: blue;
   
}

.content .uc
{
    font-size: 45px;
    font-family:'Sigmar One', cursive; 
    color: green;
    /* border: 1px solid red; */
    opacity: 1;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    
}

.content .bc
{
   
   font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
   text-transform: capitalize;
   opacity: 1;
   color: white;
   font-size: 12px;
    
}

.btn
{
    
    justify-content: center;
    padding-left: 60px;
}
button
{
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border:2px solid green;
    margin-right: 40px;
    transition-duration: 1s;
   
}

.a:hover
{
  background-color:green;
  color: black;
}
```

---

Comment: `.a` does not select elements with the _element name_ `a`, it selects elements that have the _class_ `a`. Your `button` element have that class, but none of your links do.

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure there is no `whitespace` between `:` and `hover`

`a: hover` ❌

`a:hover`  ✔

Just add

```
a:hover {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

and it would work like a charm

```css
.content {
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  /* border: 1px yellow solid; */
  margin-top: 200px;
  color: blue;
}

.content .uc {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
  color: green;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  opacity: 1;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.content .bc {
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.btn {
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 60px;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  ;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-right: 40px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.a:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="logo">Tiger</h1>

<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Timings</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Diet</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Weather<a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="content">
  <h1 class="uc">I'm the true king of the jungle</h1>


  <p class="bc" style="text-transform: capitalize important!;">Tiger are mavericks,these big cats are extremely fierce and its heart pumping to come accross one in real worlk.
  </p>

  <div class="btn">
    <button class="a">White Tiger</button>
    <button class="a">Yellow Tiger</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi decpk, I made sure there was no gap between the "a" and ":",still doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

The hover effect is working, but those elements are behind the `.logo`. Try adding `position` to `.menu` so that it appears over the `.logo`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(tiger.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
  background-color: orange;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  opacity: .8;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -120px;
  font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

a:hover {
  color: green;
  opacity: .9;
}

.content {
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  /* border: 1px yellow solid; */
  margin-top: 200px;
  color: blue;
}

.content .uc {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
  color: green;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  opacity: 1;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.content .bc {
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.btn {
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 60px;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  ;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-right: 40px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.a:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Layout with HTML and CSS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Layout1.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Modak&family=Sigmar+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <h1 class="logo">Tiger</h1>

  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Timings</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Diet</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Weather<a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="content">
    <h1 class="uc">I'm the true king of the jungle</h1>


    <p class="bc" style="text-transform: capitalize important!;">Tiger are mavericks,these big cats are extremely fierce and its heart pumping to come accross one in real worlk.
    </p>

    <div class="btn">
      <button class="a">White Tiger</button>
      <button class="a">Yellow Tiger</button>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: BEAUTY! that was it, logo was covering the links.. Thanks for the solution, really appreciate..

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad that solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li a:hover{
   color: green !important;
   opacity: .9 !important;
}
```

It will definitely work. Try this.

Comment: Hi Joseph, appreciate your response, I used the above code as you typed, unfortunately still the anchor links are dead..